# C# JsonSerialize with no member names

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I have the following classes that I like to serialize to Json. I'm currently getting something like this

```
 var pgdata =   {"SeriesList":[{"label":"Fund","data":[{"Year":2000,"RateOfReturn":0.02},{"Year":2009,"RateOfReturn":0.03}]},{"label":"Benchmark","data":[{"Year":2000,"RateOfReturn":0.024},{"Year":2009,"RateOfReturn":0.032}]}]} ;
```

I like to get something like this

```
var pgdata =   {"SeriesList":[{"label":"Fund","data":[[2000,0.02],[2009,0.03]]},{"label":"Benchmark","data":[[2000,0.024],[2009,0.032]]}]} ;
```

C# Code:

```
public class JsonPerformGraphData
    {
        public List<Series> SeriesList = new List<Series>();

        public Series GetSeries(string name)
        {
            foreach (Series s in SeriesList)
            {
                if (s.label == name)
                    return s;
            }

            Series series = new Series(name);
            SeriesList.Add(series);
            return series;
        }

        public void Add(PerformanceGraphItem ppgi)
        {
            Series s = GetSeries(ppgi.PerformanceGraphSeries.Name);
            s.addItem(ppgi.Year, ppgi.RateOfReturn);
        }


        public class Series
        {
            public string label;
            public List<Data> data = new List<Data>();

            public Series(String name)
            {
                label = name;
            }

            public void addItem(short year, double rateOfReturn)
            {

                data.Add(new Data(year,rateOfReturn));

            }
        }

        public class Data
        {
            public short Year;
            public double RateOfReturn;

            public Data(short year, double rateOfReturn)
            {
                Year = year;
                RateOfReturn = rateOfReturn;
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there a particular reason you're not using [json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/)?  It has already solved the serialization problem for C# developers and there's fairly few reasons not to use it.  The only problem I had with it related to its inflexibility with using interface objects in deserialization from JSON, but unless you are doing unit testing on this class that shouldn't be an issue (and it doesn't look like you are).

For your purposes, json.NET should give you the output you're looking for, with no muss or fuss on rolling a serializer all by yourself.

edit: Also, just to be clear, json.NET does support serializing without member names the way you're wanting.  Simply add a [JsonProperty Attribute](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute.htm) to each member.